# How to change the bar color (Not the background) of progressView in SWIFTUI iOS16?

Tags: swiftui

How to change the actual bar color, for the progress view?
I tried with the common methods, but does not seem to work and when checking the documentation inside xcode it says tint deprecated.
How to fix?

Here is my code:

```
ProgressView()
    .progressViewStyle(LinearProgressViewStyle(tint: .red))
    .background(.yellow)
```

I want the bar to be red.
How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put `tint` on the view. Like so:

```
ProgressView(value: 0.5)
    .progressViewStyle(LinearProgressViewStyle())
    .tint(.red) // <-- Right here
    .background(.yellow)
```

**Hope this helps :)**